# Redirect if there are no posts in the category Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I want to redirect users back if they have selected a category that has no posts. I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$check = Category::withCount('posts')->first();
if($cheсk->posts_count < 1){
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
  }
```

Or:

```
if(Category::withCount('posts') < 1){
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
  }
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id',
        'code',
        'img'
    ];

    public function posts(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you mention your Category Model? it helps to a better understanding

Comment: Sure, updated the post.

Comment: The first approach is correct but you always get `$check = Category::withCount('posts')->first();` instead of the category that corresponds to the route taken

Comment: And how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use following code:
$isCategoryHasPosts = Category::where('id','<specify_category_id>')->has('posts')->count();
if(!$isCategoryHasPosts) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
}
```

Note: replace specify_category_id with your actual category Id.

Comment: Thank you! The `has` function is exactly what I needed.